# Webpack: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, babeljs

In my `PHP` project - I am trying to build my `js` files using webpack and babel. There are 3 `js` files - `config.js helper.js script.js`. They have dependency on each other. `helper.js` is dependent on `config.js` and `script.js` is dependent on `helper.js`.

```
config.js:

module.exports = {
  const DG_GRAPH_TYPE = 'line';

  const DG_XAXIS_TICKS = 4;

  const DG_SINGLE_POST_GRAPH_CANVAS_HEIGHT = 250;
  ......



helper.js:

const config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
......



script.js:

const helper = require('./helper');

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
......
```

Here is my `wepack.config.js` file where I configured with following code:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        script: [
            './assets/js/script.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')]
                    }
                },
                parser: {
          amd: false, // disable AMD
          commonjs: false, // disable CommonJS
          system: false, // disable SystemJS
          harmony: true, // disable ES2015 Harmony import/export
          requireInclude: false, // disable require.include
          requireEnsure: false, // disable require.ensure
          requireContext: false, // disable require.context
          browserify: true, // disable special handling of Browserify bundles
          requireJs: true, // disable requirejs.*
          node: false, // disable __dirname, __filename, module, require.extensions, require.main, etc.
        }
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Everything works fine except when I add the built script file within project, I get following browser console error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at Object.
>   (script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
>       at a (script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
>       at Object. (script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
>       at a (script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
>       at script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1
>       at script.bundle.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1

What I was expecting `require.js` should solve the issue. But it doesn't.

Can you please suggest me the appropriate way to solve the issue?

**EDIT**

The main concept of the work is just to build multiple `js` files in one place also adding babel to make it browser friendly if I have to add ES6/ES7.

My main `js` file is `script.js` which its has two dependencies `config.js` and `helper.js`. So, I was to build only `script.js` where I wanted to `import/require` dependencies file there.

At first I tried to entry all `js` files, but all I got `script.js` was built not others. -

```
entry: {
        script: [
            './assets/js/config.js'
            './assets/js/helper.js'
            './assets/js/script.js'
        ]
    },
```

Here is the `package.json` -

```
{
  "name": "GRAPH",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Graph plugin",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "ABC",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  }
}
```

Also, yes. I was adding the built `js` file in `<script>` tag.

**END EDIT**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you "building"? . It looks like you are just including the script in the browser's `<script>` tag. `require` only works in a `node` environment. After the build process, the transformed javascript will be understood by the browser. If you edit your answer to include what buildsteps you are running, I could look into it more. also, are there any scripts in your `package.json`?

Comment: @axm__ Thanks for your comment. I updated my question.

Comment: Your `package.json` mentions `{ build: webpack }`. Did you actually run `npm run build` to run the command? If not, could you do so before I try to answer the question and tell me what the output is. The command should output the built file to the output path you mentioned in `webpack.config.json` . To read more about npm scripts: https://michael-kuehnel.de/tooling/2018/03/22/helpers-and-tips-for-npm-run-scripts.html

Comment: @axm__ yes, I built the output `js` file using `npm run build`. When I add the output `js` file and add it to `<script>` tag in browser console I get the error `require is undefined`.

Comment: Ok, that is weird. How does your output file look like? Can you see if there is any transform at all?

Comment: Yes, In output file, I see `script.js` file is built perfectly but don't get others two files built.

Comment: So, my headache is to `import/require` other two `js` files within `script.js` files. When I `require` `helper.js` file within `script.js` actually `require is not undefined` error shows up in console.

Comment: This is the code above in `script.js` - `const helper = require('./helper');` which is not triggering

Comment: ok. Why did you set `module.parser.node` to `false` ?  webpack is run in node and uses the nodejs module resolution. what happens if you change it to `true` and requirejs to `false`

Comment: still same issue

Comment: `module.parser.node` to `false` this is a default option. What I was up to `require` others files with `require.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181070/discussion-between-axm-and-user3384985).

Answer (score 5):

You need to build the bundle first to make it understandable to the browser. The error `require is not defined` gives you the hint that you are not in an `node` environment (it was not called by something like `node runthiscurrentprogram.js` or by a program that runs `node` for you. Read more about the output format with `require` [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/)

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) is a bundler that runs in `node` that can bundle and/or transform source files (could be javascript, css, etc.) and places them where you want. The bundles file can be included in a `<script>` tag to make it understandable to the browser.

To run webpack either run `npm run build` (because you have a script named `build` in your `package.json` scripts or `npx webpack` (more about `npx` [here](https://alligator.io/workflow/npx/)). What this does is call the `webpack` executable in `/path_to_your_project/node_modules/.bin/webpack`. If you open that file, you will see it is run in node (it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env node`)

Now you mention that your main file is `script.js` which "requires" those other files. In that case you only have to put `script.js` in the webpack entry. Webpack automatically bundles the required files in the bundle. All the code will be out put in your `outputPath` in a single file. (There are ways/reasons to have multiple entries, but not in your case I guess, [read more here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)).

So run `npm run webpack` , `npx webpack` and look at the output path if there's a new file there and include *that* file in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: The problem is `script.js` file can't require other two files. That's why in `console` I get the error. So, what is the appropriate way to `require` other two `js` within `script.js`?

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function does not exist in browsers, only in Node environments. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined).

Answer (score 0):

I arrived to the same error but, instead of using `webpack` I used `gulp`. `Babel` transpiled ES6 to ES5 but it failed to comply with `import` and `required` statements. In short, [gulp-bro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bro) library saved my day. You can find step by step instructions in this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043032/browserify-parseerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype/56851445#56851445).